# Can I pass a reference to an instance function of a particular object?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Is it possible to do the same as in [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) and pass a function reference to a function of a particular object in javascript?

Consider the following code:

```
_.every(aS, function (value) {
    return exp.test(value);
});
```

I would like to do:

```
_.every(aS, exp.test);
```

I.e. cause the `test` function of that particular `RegExp` to be called.

Is this possible in javascript?

---

Answer: Yes it is possible, take a look at [chapter 2 of You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) section *Hard Binding*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but to be sure the `this` reference is working correctly inside the `exp.text` implementation, you should [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) it:

```
_.every(aS, exp.test.bind(exp));
```

For some functions, this may not be necessary (when they don't use the `this` reference), but it does not hurt.

For more information on `this`, see [How does the `this` keyword work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work).

Comment: A good explanation is at [chapter 2 of You Don't Know JS: this & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md) section *Hard Binding*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you have to have a bit of an understanding of how [this](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/README.md) works in JS.

Basically, you have to bind the function to the object like this.

```
_.every(aS, exp.test.bind(exp))
```

Basically, when you use `bind`, it makes sure that no matter where the function is called, the `this` is always bound to the object you pass into the function. If you didn't call `bind` then `this` would be bound to whatever the environments global object is, `window` in the browser.